# How to avoid multiple inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

For a project, I have following classes:

- SuperClass
- Subclass 1
- Subclass 2

The two subclasses extend the superclass.
Now, I need a third class with the EXACT behaviour (read, same overriden method implementations) of both SubClass 1 and Subclass 2.
Because Subclass 1 overrides only 1 method in SuperClass, and Subclass 2 doesn't override that method, I want to make the third class inherit Superclass and just implement it with the methods of Subclass 1 and Subclass 2. Now, is this good OO-design? I see no other solution because multiple inheritance in Java just isn't possible. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Favour composition over inheritance...

Comment: It'd be useful to see the class definitions and how you'll use them to say whether it's good design

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java8 introduced **default** and **static** methods for interfaces. To a certain degree, that allows for multiple inheritance. But most likely, the correct solution would be to rework your design.

You see, inheritance is **not** about code re-use. It is about creating useful abstractions; and make good use of polymorphism for example.

In your case: maybe those functionalities could/should be put into smaller interfaces; and then segregated into their own, independent classes. And then you use **composition** of objects instead of inheritance to build the thing you need.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using Java 8's default methods as @GhostCat mentioned. I don't see anything wrong with this OO design per se. Whether or not it's appropriate to your use case depends on the details of the problem you're solving.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SuperClass sc = new SubClass3();
        sc.foo();  // overridden foo
        sc.bar();  // overridden bar
    }

    interface SuperClass {
        default void foo() {
            System.out.println("default foo");
        }
        default void bar() {
            System.out.println("default bar");
        }
    }

    interface SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
        @Override
        default void foo() {
            System.out.println("overridden foo");
        }
    }

    interface SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
        @Override
        default void bar() {
            System.out.println("overridden bar");
        }
    }

    static class SubClass3 implements SubClass1, SubClass2 {}
}
```